# Best IDE for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

With WPF I used Expression Blend for design and Visual Studio for development. Is there a similar setup for ASP.NET MVC or are design and development all done in the same application?

I have Visual Studio 2010, Expression Web 4 and I notice on Microsoft's website there is an another application called Visual Web Developer Express 2008. So which of these applications should I be using for ASP.NET applications?

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC doesn't have a designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551300/asp-net-mvc-razor-designer); and I don't know of any commercial ones, either. That doesn't mean they don't exist, but I would expect the majority of MVC developers / UI designers do not use an IDE designer. Drag-and-drop development for the web had lead to very ugly results.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 is fine, for Razor view engine there is no designer and since it is not XAML based Expression would not work as designer.

It's a bit uncomfortable initially but in the end you get used to it, the web browser is your tool to visualize the View and there is no visual designer.

it looks like in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview (together with the Windows 8 Dev Preview) they have added a Razor designer but I have not seen it yet myself and anyway is a pre-beta and we should not use it in production, which leaves only the good old Visual Studio 2010 SP1 as valid alternative and reference tool.